# Why does <script> tag always require </script> to make js file loads? Why doesn't the <script src ="content"/> work?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, tags

I don not see any reason why the close tag "/" at the end of  never works when you need to import a JavaScript.
I had to go through a thousand line code just to find that this was the bug. Shouldnt HTML automatically parse the end of tag closes?

Comment: I suspect because script tags can have actual script within them.

Comment: Because that is how the tag is required to be.

Comment: I firmly believe there must be an explanation why specifically just this tag <script> cannot be closed the way any other tag be closed lets say <body/>. Any thoughts?

Comment: Looks like I found the answer after looking it up. The script tag is a content holding tag and would be requiring it to conform with th elikes of Paragrah and title tags that camnnot be self closed. This is because the Script tag accoriding to XHTML specs was designed to hold CDATA in it. And hence will be a good point to note for future debugging that we should not self close scrip tags.